# systemctl --user start docker-desktop doesn't launch docker-desktop. docker-desktop NEVER LAUNCHES

Tags: linux, docker, launch, launcher, docker-desktop

I am trying to get familiar with docker and docker engine. I have succesfully installed docker engine (the 'hello world' test runs with no issues). I have also correctly installed docker-desktop (as a matter of fact I have the icon on the menu as normal) but if I try to launch it by clicking it, or right-click launch it never starts.

I've even tried booting it with the command from the terminal
`systemctl --user start docker-desktop`
but still nothing.

My os is Linux Mint 19.3
Let me know if you need any diagnostics.

Thank you very much in advance for any help :)

Comment: You don't need Docker Desktop on native Linux; just directly use `docker` commands targeting the local engine.

Comment: I know I don't need it, but it's such a convenient tool for visualizing everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact problem and google brought me here. I was running a ubuntu VM inside VirtualBox for Windows. When the VM was not running, it was fixed by enabling:

Settings->System->Processor->Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V

So whether your host is virtual or physical, make sure it has virtualization enabled.

More information [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/vm-vdi/).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for sharing man :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the docker desktop is not running in the background. I experienced the same issue. Then realized it was already running, so this command seemed not to be working. So don't try to start something that has started already.

Comment: I just gave up on it a long time ago. I just got good at using the command line (which is not a bad idea btw). Still, thank you very much for the tip :)